# Selecting a DataFrame column which is in datetime.time(x, y) format (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I am trying to select a column using the standard df['columnName'] format in pandas, but my column names are hh:mm:ss and so i am getting errors (see below).

---df---

```
Date       00:00:00  00:30:00 01:00:00

01/01/2015     1.05      2.01     3.10

02/01/2015     2.40      4.50     6.72

03/01/2015     1.10      0.68     8.91
```

list(df)

```
['Date', datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(0, 30), datetime.time(1, 0)]
```

df.columns

```
Index(['Date', 00:00:00, 00:30:00, 01:00:00], dtype='object')
```

My attempt 1:

```
df[datetime.time(1, 00)]

NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

My attempt 2:

```
df['01:00:00']

KeyError: '01:00:00'
```

I just want to select a column labelled "01:00:00"

Comment: Looks like you forgot `import datetime`. Try again with `df[datetime.time(1, 00)]`.

Comment: How did you create that input dataframe?

Comment: Ah silly me! Thank you